# MaxAuthTries is being crazy

Tags: ssh, vps, ovh

I just installed a breand new OVH VPS. When it was delivered I tried to login using the credentials given by OVH. When I am trying to SSH with root (for the first time !) I have the following message:

> "Received disconnect from XX.XX.XX.XX port 22:2: Too many authentication failures"

I used KVM to enter the VPS. When I change MaxAuthTries with

```
MaxAuthTries 1234
```

it works.

I can login my VPS.

I then enter:

```
root@vpsXXXXX:~# pam_tally2 --user=root
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
root                0
```

I don't understand. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have _many_ keys in your SSH agent?

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you, I have more than 6 keys. But why it appears to be no failures according to pam_tally2 ?

Comment: Did you restart the sshd after modifying sshd_config? The public key authentication does not go through pam so pam_tally does not see that.

Comment: Yes I restarted it, that is why it worked after modifying it. Ok pam_tally does not see public keys auths. Thanks to you both.